# Where are docker man pages?

Tags: 14.04, manpage, docker

I'm desperately searching for a .deb package with docker man pages. Any idea? I have stable 14.04.

Just to be clear, I'm asking for the man pages for https://www.docker.com/

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed "Docker" with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

the man pages can be viewed with:

```
man docker
```

Even if you have installed *Docker* with [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) the man pages can be viewed with:

```
man docker
```

With this command, you see the files installed for the man pages:

```
dpkg-query -L <package_name> | grep "/usr/share/man"
```

E.G. `docker.io`:

```
apt-cache policy docker.io

docker.io:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0~dfsg1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1.5.0~dfsg1-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages


apt-file list docker.io | grep "/usr/share/man"

docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-attach.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-build.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-commit.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-cp.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-create.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-diff.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-events.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-exec.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-export.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-history.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-images.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-import.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-info.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-inspect.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-kill.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-load.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-login.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-logout.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-logs.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-pause.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-port.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-ps.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-pull.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-push.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-restart.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-rm.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-rmi.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-run.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-save.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-search.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-start.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-stop.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-tag.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-top.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-unpause.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-version.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker-wait.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
docker.io: /usr/share/man/man5/Dockerfile.5.gz
```

Comment: dpkg -l docker.io, the package contains no man pages.

Comment: The command "dpkg -l docker.io" says nothing about the installed man pages.

Comment: Try this: "dpkg-query -L <package_name> | grep man"

Comment: @smrt28, use capital L instead to list files `dpkg -L docker.io` see `man dpkg` . As you see the file list here too http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/docker.io/filelist

Comment: Of course I mentioned -L ;-).  Yes, there is man/man1/docker.io.1.gz. But it is the only man page in the deb package. Where are the others? For instance I'm missing "man docker run"? For comparison, see the debian https://packages.debian.org/sid/armel/docker.io/filelist
It has 40+- man pages there. There is just 1 in ubuntu.

Comment: @smrt28 I have 42. :) Installed from here: https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: @smrt28 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a bug in ubuntu 14.04.1

```
~$ apt-cache policy docker.io
docker.io:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.1~dfsg1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     1.0.1~dfsg1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.9.1~dfsg1-2 0
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

install by `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh` helps.